# C - Need help debugging Chess function

Tags: c

I'm new to C and programming in general. I've implemented C and am almost done, but it appears that the function that checks if a piece is attacked is wrong. I would appreciate it if anyone could have a look and perhaps spot something that I cant:

```
int isAttacked(game_t* game, int x, int y, int color)
{
    /*printf("entered IA");*/
    int i, j,m, curX, curY, range;
    int dx[] = { 0, 1, 0, -1 };
    int dy[] = { 1, 0, -1, 0 };
    char en = BLACK_N, eb = BLACK_B, er = BLACK_R, eq = BLACK_Q, ek = BLACK_K, ep = BLACK_P;
    if (!color)
    {
        en = WHITE_N;
        eb = WHITE_B;
        er = WHITE_R;
        eq = WHITE_Q;
        ek = WHITE_K;
        ep = WHITE_P;
    }

    for (i = -2; i <= 2; i++)  /* KNIGHT ATTACKING */
        for (j = -2; j <= 2; j++)
            if (ABS(i) + ABS(j) == 3 && isValidCoords(x + i, y + j) && game->board[x + i][y + j] == en)
                return 1;

    for (i = -1; i <= 1; i += 2)
    {
        for (j = -1; j <= 1; j += 2)
        {
            curX = x;
            curY = y;
            range = 0;
            while (isValidCoords(curX + i, curY + j) == 1)          
            {
                range++;
                curX += i;
                curY += j;
                if(game->board[curX][curY] != EMPTY)
                    break;
            }


            if (game->board[curX][curY] == eq) /*BISHOP OR QUEEN ATTACKING*/
                return 1;
            if(game->board[curX][curY] == eb)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if (range == 1 && game->board[curX][curY] == ek) /*KING ATTACKING*/
                return 1;
            if (range == 1 && color && j == 1 && game->board[curX][curY] == ep)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (range == 1 && !color && j == -1 && game->board[curX][curY] == ep)
            {
                return 1;
            }


        }
    }

    for (m = 0; m<4; m++)
    {
        curX = x;
        curY = y;
        range = 0;
        while (isValidCoords(curX + dx[m], curY + dy[m]))
        {
            curX += dx[m];
            curY += dy[m];
            range++;
            if(game->board[curX][curY] != EMPTY)
                break;
        }

        if (game->board[curX][curY] == eq)
            return 1;
        if(game->board[curX][curY] == er) /*ROOK OR QUEEN ATTACKING*/
        {
            /*printf("x %d  y   %d\n",x,y);*/
            return 1;
        }
        if (range == 1 && game->board[curX][curY] == ek)
            return 1;


    }

    return 0;
}
```

very turn, I have a list of moves. Moves can only be added to that list if after the move is done, the player's king isn't attacked, i.e., isAttacked returns 0. To check if a player's king is attacked, I recieve the king's coordinates (i,j)[these are numbers from 0 to 7] and color [either 0 or 1]. Then I check if there's enemy knight (ek) within the board (isValidCoords checks that 0<=x,y<=7) that can attack the king. Then I go to the diagonals to check if there's an enemey pawn, bishop, king, or queen that can attack the king. I do the same for rook movements. The latter 2 are wrong..I think – 
An example board where the check fails to detect the bishop attacking the king:

```
 |-------------------------------|
8| R | N | B |   |  | B | N | R |
 |-------------------------------|
7| P | P | P |   | P | K | P | P |
 |-------------------------------|
6|   |   |   | Q |   |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
5|   |   |   |   |   |   |   | |
 |-------------------------------|
4|   |   | b |   | P |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
3|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
2| p | p | p | p |   | p | p | p |
 |-------------------------------|
1| r | n | b |   | k |   | n | r |
 |-------------------------------|
```

Black pieces are in capital, white pieces are in lowercase.

The colors are represented by black - 0 and white - 1. I'm having problems detecting bishop/rook checks but I can't seem to pinpoint the mistake. Any help at all would be appreciated !

Comment: What behavior do you want to see? What behavior do you actually see? Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: You might also try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JeremyStein: No, Code Review is only for **already working** code.

Comment: If you can explaining your problem clearly, we can help you better. Sometimes restating EXACTLY what the problem is will lead you to the solution. Explain what your code does and what it is doing wrong.

Comment: Every turn, I have a list of moves. Moves can only be added to that list if after the move is done, the player's king isn't attacked, i.e., isAttacked returns 0. To check if a player's king is attacked, I recieve the king's coordinates (i,j)[these are numbers from 0 to 7] and color [either 0 or 1]. Then I check if there's enemy knight (ek) within the board (isValidCoords checks that 0<=x,y<=7) that can attack the king. Then I go to the diagonals to check if there's an enemey pawn, bishop, king, or queen that can attack the king. I do the same for rook movements. The latter 2 are wrong..I think

Comment: @Robert Can you edit your question to include that new information. Also, can you provide a board setup where you know what the out come should be but is calculated incorrectly?

Comment: You should perhaps split your function into many smaller ones, like one function for each piece type. Then you can create a minimal example just for the functions which don't work.

Comment: You can debug this with simple print statements.  The very first thing you should print in the function is `printf("Checking piece @ %d,%d: %c\n", x, y, game->board[x][y]);`.  Then in the `for` loop, you print what piece you are looking at and what position:  `printf("  Found %c at %d,%d [is bishop? %s]\n", game->board[curX][curY], curX, curY, game->board[curX][curY] == eb ? "yes" : "no");`.  That will tell you precisely whether you are even looking at the correct piece.  One red flag:  I don't understand why you need `color`.  You can infer the color from the piece at x,y...

Comment: I'm now trying both to split up the function and to use prints, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem may lie within either the coordinates you're feeding into the routine or perhaps a problem with your `isValidCoords` routine.  To test your code as posted I supplied this driver:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char board[8][8];
} game_t;

int isValidCoords(int x, int y)
{
    return (x >= 0) && (y >= 0) && (x < 8) && (y < 8);
}

enum pieces { EMPTY, 
              BLACK_N, BLACK_B, BLACK_R, BLACK_Q, BLACK_K, BLACK_P, 
              WHITE_N, WHITE_B, WHITE_R, WHITE_Q, WHITE_K, WHITE_P };

const char pieceabbrev[] = " NBRQKPnbrqkp";

#define BLACK 0
#define WHITE 1

int ABS(int i)
{
    return i < 0 ? -i : i;
}
void showboard(game_t *game)
{
    const char hline[] ="\n |-------------------------------|";

    puts(hline);
    for (int y=7; y>=0; --y) {
        printf("%d|", y);
        for (int x=0; x < 8; ++x) {
            printf(" %c |", pieceabbrev[game->board[x][y]]);
        }   
        puts(hline);
    }   
    printf("  ");
    for (int x=0; x < 8; ++x) {
        printf(" %d  ", x);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
Y
 |-------------------------------|
7| R | N | B |   |   | B | N | R |
 |-------------------------------|
6| P | P | P |   | P | K | P | P |
 |-------------------------------|
5|   |   |   | Q |   |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
4|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
3|   |   | b |   | P |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
2|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
1| p | p | p | p |   | p | p | p |
 |-------------------------------|
0| r | n | b |   | k |   | n | r |
 |-------------------------------|
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7     X
 lowercase is white
 Uppercase is Black
*/
int main()
{
    game_t game;
    for (int i=0; i < 8; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j < 8; ++j)
            game.board[i][j] = EMPTY;

    game.board[0][7] = BLACK_R;
    game.board[1][7] = BLACK_N;
    game.board[2][7] = BLACK_B;
    game.board[3][7] = EMPTY;
    game.board[4][7] = EMPTY;
    game.board[5][7] = BLACK_B;
    game.board[6][7] = BLACK_N;
    game.board[7][7] = BLACK_R;

    game.board[0][6] = BLACK_P;
    game.board[1][6] = BLACK_P;
    game.board[2][6] = BLACK_P;
    game.board[3][6] = EMPTY;
    game.board[4][6] = BLACK_P;
    game.board[5][6] = BLACK_K;
    game.board[6][6] = BLACK_P;
    game.board[7][6] = BLACK_P;

    game.board[3][5] = BLACK_Q;

    game.board[2][3] = WHITE_B;
    game.board[4][3] = WHITE_P;

    game.board[0][1] = WHITE_P;
    game.board[1][1] = WHITE_P;
    game.board[2][1] = WHITE_P;
    game.board[3][1] = WHITE_P;
    game.board[4][1] = EMPTY;
    game.board[5][1] = WHITE_P;
    game.board[6][1] = WHITE_P;
    game.board[7][1] = WHITE_P;

    game.board[0][0] = WHITE_R;
    game.board[1][0] = WHITE_N;
    game.board[2][0] = WHITE_B;
    game.board[3][0] = EMPTY;
    game.board[4][0] = WHITE_K;
    game.board[5][0] = EMPTY;
    game.board[6][0] = WHITE_N;
    game.board[7][0] = WHITE_R;

    printf("attacked = %d\n", isAttacked(&game, 5, 6, BLACK));

    showboard(&game);
}
```

I then instrumented your code.  Everywhere it originally had a `return 1;` I changed it to this:

```
{
    printf("%c is attacking from (%d,%d)\n", 
           pieceabbrev[game->board[curX][curY]], curX, curY);
    return 1;
}
```

Program output:

```
b is attacking from (2,3)
attacked = 1

 |-------------------------------|
7| R | N | B |   |   | B | N | R |
 |-------------------------------|
6| P | P | P |   | P | K | P | P |
 |-------------------------------|
5|   |   |   | Q |   |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
4|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
3|   |   | b |   | p |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
2|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
 |-------------------------------|
1| p | p | p | p |   | p | p | p |
 |-------------------------------|
0| r | n | b |   | k |   | n | r |
 |-------------------------------|
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

As you can see, your routine correctly detected the attacking bishop, so I'm suspecting that the problem lies elsewhere.

Also, for what it's worth, providing a minimal but complete example (as with the code I provided) might make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: You're welcome, and I hope that you continue breaking the code into smaller pieces.  Doing so will help you to maintain and debug it as the code gains features and complexity.  Also, if you haven't got it already, consider adding test code to make sure each new routine works as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

As Tyler pointed out , your code is somewhat incorrect, but that's not the reason your example doesn't work.
I implemented a minimal working example using your function and it worked fine in your test case.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct game_s {
     char board[8][8];
} game_t;

#define EMPTY 0x20
#define BLACK_N 'N'
#define BLACK_B 'B'
#define BLACK_R 'R'
#define BLACK_Q 'Q'
#define BLACK_K 'K'
#define BLACK_P 'P'
#define WHITE_N 'n'
#define WHITE_B 'b'
#define WHITE_R 'r'
#define WHITE_Q 'q'
#define WHITE_K 'k'
#define WHITE_P 'p'

void print_board(game_t *game) {
    int i,j;
    for(j=7;j>=0;j--) {
        printf("|---------------|\n|");
        for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
            printf("%c|", game->board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("|---------------|\n");
}

int ABS(int x) {
    return (x > 0 ? x : x*-1);
}

int isValidCoords(int x, int y) {
    return (x >= 0 && y>=0 && x<8 && y<8);
}

int isAttacked(game_t *game, int x, int y, int color)
{
    /*printf("entered IA");*/
    int i, j,m, curX, curY, range;
    int dx[] = { 0, 1, 0, -1 };
    int dy[] = { 1, 0, -1, 0 };
    char en = BLACK_N, eb = BLACK_B, er = BLACK_R, eq = BLACK_Q, ek = BLACK_K, ep = BLACK_P;
    if (!color)
    {
        en = WHITE_N;
        eb = WHITE_B;
        er = WHITE_R;
        eq = WHITE_Q;
        ek = WHITE_K;
        ep = WHITE_P;
    }

    for (i = -2; i <= 2; i++)  /* KNIGHT ATTACKING */
        for (j = -2; j <= 2; j++)
            if (ABS(i) + ABS(j) == 3 && isValidCoords(x + i, y + j) && game->board[x + i][y + j] == en) {
                return 1;
            }

    for (i = -1; i <= 1; i += 2)
    {
        for (j = -1; j <= 1; j += 2)
        {
            curX = x;
            curY = y;
            range = 0;
            while (isValidCoords(curX + i, curY + j) == 1)
            {
                range++;
                curX += i;
                curY += j;
                if(game->board[curX][curY] != EMPTY)
                    break;
            }


            if (game->board[curX][curY] == eq) { /*BISHOP OR QUEEN ATTACKING*/
                return 1;
            }
            if(game->board[curX][curY] == eb)
            {
            printf("ATTACK from %s Bishop at %c%c\n", color ? "black" : "white", curX+'A', curY+'1');
                return 1;
            }

            if (range == 1 && game->board[curX][curY] == ek) { /*KING ATTACKING*/
                return 1;
            }
            if (range == 1 && color && j == 1 && game->board[curX][curY] == ep)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (range == 1 && !color && j == -1 && game->board[curX][curY] == ep)
            {
                return 1;
            }


        }
    }

    for (m = 0; m<4; m++)
    {
        curX = x;
        curY = y;
        range = 0;
        while (isValidCoords(curX + dx[m], curY + dy[m]))
        {
            curX += dx[m];
            curY += dy[m];
            range++;
            if(game->board[curX][curY] != EMPTY)
                break;
        }

        if (game->board[curX][curY] == eq)
            return 1;
        if(game->board[curX][curY] == er) /*ROOK OR QUEEN ATTACKING*/
        {
            /*printf("x %d  y   %d\n",x,y);*/
            return 1;
        }
        if (range == 1 && game->board[curX][curY] == ek)
            return 1;


    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char my_board[8][8] = { {WHITE_R, WHITE_P, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK_P, BLACK_R},
            {WHITE_N, WHITE_P, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK_P, BLACK_N},
            {WHITE_B, WHITE_P, EMPTY, WHITE_B, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK_P, BLACK_B},
            {EMPTY, WHITE_P, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK_Q, EMPTY, EMPTY},
            {WHITE_K, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK_P, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK_P, EMPTY},
            {EMPTY, WHITE_P, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK_K, BLACK_B},
            {WHITE_N, WHITE_P, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK_P, BLACK_N},
            {WHITE_R, WHITE_P, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK_P, BLACK_R}};
    game_t my_game;
    memcpy(my_game.board, my_board, 64);

    isAttacked(&my_game, 5, 6, 0);

    print_board(&my_game);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ATTACK from white Bishop at C4
|---------------|
|R|N|B| | |B|N|R|
|---------------|
|P|P|P| |P|K|P|P|
|---------------|
| | | |Q| | | | |
|---------------|
| | | | | | | | |
|---------------|
| | |b| |P| | | |
|---------------|
| | | | | | | | |
|---------------|
|p|p|p|p| |p|p|p|
|---------------|
|r|n|b| |k| |n|r|
|---------------|
```

So it seems the reason you cant detect the attacking bishop is most likely hiding in the surrounding code.

You should also split up your function in smaller ones, to ease debugging.

Edit: Edward beat me to it, so i just agree with him

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the handling of the exit condition from the following loop:

`while (isValidCoords(curX + i, curY + j) == 1)`

If `isValidCoords` returns false (0), then the loop exits and the procedure continues using invalid values of `curX` and `curY`.

In other words this loop has two possible exit conditions: (1) either the coordinate is not on the board, or (2) the square represented by the coordinate has a piece on it. You are treating both conditions the same way. One way to fix this problem is the following:

```
while ( true ){
    if( isValidCoords(curX + i, curY + j) == 1 ) goto NextAttackCheck;
    range++;
    curX += i;
    curY += j;
    if( game->board[curX][curY] != EMPTY ) break;
}
```

The label `NextAttackCheck:` should be located before the close brace of the j-loop.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  I think it's a precondition that `x` and `y` is a valid board position.  So initially, `curX` and `curY` is valid.  Then he's walking the board until he gets to the edge or finds a piece.  `isValidCoords` only returns 0 when he is at the edge and he sees that changing `curX` and `curY` would put him off the board.  And in that case he doesn't change `curX` and `curY` so they never become invalid.

Comment: @indiv Yes, but even so, the code is wrong for the same reason, which is an invalid exit from the loop. For example, if the origin square (x,y) is on the edge of the board, then the loop will exit and the origin square itself will be tested for the presence of an enemy piece. So, any way you slice it, the exit conditions on the loop are wrong.